# Google maps map not loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

I've read a ton of solutions about my problem, but non of them worked for me. My map is not loading

Here is my html

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.7429109,24.391538699999955)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">


            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
```

The css I think the problem is somewhere here

```
    body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    background:#302f2f ;
}

  #map_canvas {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
  }
```

So please help me

Comment: map-canvas is not the same as map_canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html element has the ID 'map_canvas', your javascript has it as 'map-canvas'.

It simply cannot find the element cos you're spelling the ID wrong! :o)

Comment: Thank you I make so many mistakes like this and it is hard for me to find them

Comment: easiest way for me is to run google chrome and press F12 - this will show any error messages and will usually take you to the problem in the code if you click on the error message. After a while you begin to associate certain messages with common slip ups.